# Proper Structure for Saving Date and Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to save user information and display it into a UITableViewCell as:

(date) - (value)

Like:

(12/12/2014) - (240lbs)

I'm unsure of what structure type to use. I need to save 2 different objects (the nsdate and nstring values described above) and be able to iterate through them by key (date and value) to display the text for each within the uitableview.

Comment: Why don't you create a class that has a date and a string variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't `NSDictionary` what you're looking for?
Example:

```
NSDictionary *myKeys = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSDate date], @"date",
                            [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:240], @"weight",
                            nil];
```

Pay attention to the order "Objects and Keys". Here I used `@"date"` and `@"weight"` as the keys names. Then you can access the objects by doing:

```
myKeys[@"weight"]
```

or

```
myKeys[@"date"]
```

And if you want to have multiple entries relating date and weight, you can use an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`.

Updated after you provided more context: if the user needs to log something, Core Data is the way to go. The Core Data entities work very similarly to `NSDictionary`'s but they will actually be `NSManagedObject`'s contained inside an `NSManagedObjectContext`. You should create an entity with two properties: date and weight.

Comment: Yes, that seems right, except i will have numerous dates and weights (one for each day).

Comment: I got that. That's why I strongly recommend you to use Core Data, otherwise you will lose all your entries every time the application is closed - and this is something expected to happen as the user will be day after day adding entries. Maybe the following tutorial can be helpful to you: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/56879/magicalrecord-tutorial-ios)

Answer (score 2):

**NSDictionary**
[NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). A dictionary is similar to an array, but allows you to store objects and keys. Dictionaries allow you to assign specific keys to objects and then retrieve an object from its key. Here's the description straight from Apple:

> The NSDictionary class declares the programmatic interface to objects that manage immutable associations of keys and values. Use this class or its subclass NSMutableDictionary when you need a convenient and efficient way to retrieve data associated with an arbitrary key. NSDictionary creates static dictionaries, and NSMutableDictionary creates dynamic dictionaries.

**Formating**
For example, you could save a dictionary of weights and dates (see below) and then retrieve the weight object using the date key (or vice versa).

```
   Key     |  Object
-----------|----------
12/12/2014 |  240 lbs
10/08/2014 |  250 lbs
09/25/2014 |  262 lbs
```

Here you'll want to save the keys (dates) as [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) objects and the objects (weight) as [NSNumbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html).

**Saving and Setup**
How to setup an NSDictionary? Just like this:

```
// A generic NSDictionary setup
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key": @"object", @"key2": @"object2"};

// An NSDictionary setup for NSDates and NSNumbers
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{[NSDate date]: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:240]};

/* There are hundreds of ways to format and use an NSDictionary.
   You could even have multiple dictionaries in an NSArray. 
   Or you could use an NSMutableDictionary and continue to add entries. */
```

**Reading and Retrieval**
When the UITableView calls its data source to populate the rows, provide the content from the dictionary. You can access the content using either keys or indexes.

Here's how you might retrieve a weight entry using the date key:

```
NSNumber *weight = [yourDictionary objectForKey:@"keyName OR NSDate object"];
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I have it currently set up this way but I can't figure out how to grab the individual objects as I don't have a key set for either. I just have the date as first value and weight as second value.

Comment: @TerryGodier What do you mean by you "don't have a key set for either"? NSDictionary needs keys to function at all - without them it's useless. If you need to access objects in another way, take a look at the documentation - there are more ways to access objects. Please clarify your comment or question. And remember to up vote if this is helpful.

Comment: I did this and it does work now - but it only saves 1 date and weight object no matter how many times I save it. Is that because the keys are the same each time?

Comment: Just to provide some more context here, the end goal is to enable a user to log weight each day and then display in a tableview. Is my key for each weight the 'date' then? How would I populate a UItableview with this?