# NSDictionary allkeys to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get my NSdictionary values into a UITableViewCell. Here is my dictionary format:

```
 {
date = "3/4/14, 3:33:01 PM Pacific Standard Time";
weight = 244;
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to populate my uitableview (which is not working).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"WeightCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}


NSArray* allKeys = [weights allKeys];

NSDictionary *obj = [allKeys objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [obj objectForKey: @"date"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [obj objectForKey:@"weight"];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". What's going wrong. Keep in mind that dictionaries have no order. The two keys could be in a different order every time.

Comment: Ok. By Not working, I'm not getting the tableview to populate with the data from my dictionary 'weights'. Maybe I am not going about it the correct way then.

Comment: You're using a dictionary object as the key of another object on another dictionary?

Comment: Yeah, i'm ridiculously confused and backwards. All I'm trying to do is store users weight + the date they entered it and then view it in tableview format. I am probably doing that the entire wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

You should try initialising the array for the tableView outside of the tableView itself... something along the lines of

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 _allKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[weights allKeys]];

}
```

Once you have initialised that data you can access it throughout the process. Also to find out how many rows your tableview needs.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [_allKeys count];
}
```

Then when you access the array into a dictionary it has retained the row count and can access it properly.

```
NSDictionary *obj = [_allKeys objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [obj objectForKey: @"date"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [obj objectForKey:@"weight"];
```

From what I can see the dictionary cant access the array at your indexPath.row because you haven't initialised the array anywhere before you use it in your tableView.

Hope that helps, T

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other posters have good suggestions. However, this line:

```
NSDictionary *obj = [allKeys objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

Is wrong. allKeys is an array of your dictionary keys, which are presumably strings.

So, you want code like this instead:

```
NSString *thisKey = allKeys[indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *obj = weights[thisKey];
```

Note that I am using the new Objective C literal syntax. The expression `weights[thisKey]` is equivalent to `[weights objectForKey: thisKey]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the definition of the `weights` object. If you want to keep adding `NSDictionary`'s to an array, you need to use an `NSMutableArray`, and you'll probably want to do that by setting it as a `@property` on your class. Let's say you added it like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *weights;
```

Then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you'll want to get the `NSDictionary` corresponding to that line by using `self.weights[indexPath.row]`. Also don't forget to instantiate `weights` before using it, otherwise it will return `nil` and no objects are going to be added to it.

P.S.: the user provided some context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184256/proper-structure-for-saving-date-and-value/) and what he probably needs is Core Data.